# TSQL Null data to '' replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following query:

```
SELECT pics.e_firedate FROM et_pics
```

Result:

```
NULL
2014-12-01 00:00:00.000
2015-04-03 00:00:00.000
NULL
NULL
```

I want to replace `NULL` values to ''.

```
CASE 
        WHEN pics.e_firedate IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE pics.e_firedate
END
```

makes `NULL` transforming to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`, which I've tried to cast and replace with no success also.

How can I achive my goal?

Comment: `SELECT ISNULL(pics.e_firedate,'') FROM et_pics`

Comment: All of the case expressions return types must be equivalent.

Comment: Do you want the resulting column to be a varchar or datetime? Why does it need to be an empty string instead of NULL? Your column is a DATETIME and not varchar, therefore a zero length string will be cast to the date you're seeing.

Comment: @tinka That makes the statement shorter, but results in the same output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because when using `CASE` expressions, the return values must have the same data type. In case they have different data types, all values are converted to the type with a [**higher data type precedence**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

And since `DATETIME` has a higher datatype than `VARCHAR`, `''` gets converted to `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS DATETIME)
```

The above will return  `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

To achieve your desired result, you should `CAST` the result to `VARCHAR`

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN e_firedate IS NULL THEN ''
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), e_firedate, 121)
END
FROM et_pics
```

---

For date formats, read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 select isNUll(CONVERT(VARCHAR,  pics.e_firedate, 120), '') e_firedate
FROM et_pics
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),pics.e_firedate,120),'') e_firedate
FROM et_pics
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast/convert datetime field, not other value - for example:

```
case 
    when pics.e_firedate is null 
    then '' 
    else cast(pics.e_firedate as nvarchar(30))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the column in your database seems to be a `DATETIME` column. So SQL Server converts `''` to the default date value.

One solution might be to convert *all* the results to string, as in:

```
 SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, pics.e_firedate), '') AS e_firedateString
 FROM et_pics
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be more efficient?   And might not.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), e_firedate, 121) FROM et_pics where pics.e_firedate is not null 
union 
SELECT ''                                    FROM et_pics where pics.e_firedate is     null
```